# Why 3d object added to scene view scene moves along with camera?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I have added 3d object to scene view scene which is in dae format. But its moving along with camera. How to fix it to a particular position. Same code works with other 3d object but issue is only with this specific object. Below is the code used:

```
 let scene = SCNScene(named: "Volvo_FE_Crane_2013.dae")!
 craneNode = SCNNode()
 let truckNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Volvo_FE_Crane_2013", recursively: true)!
 craneNode.addChildNode(truckNode.clone())
 craneNode.position = SCNVector3Make(hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
 craneNode.light?.intensity = 1000
 craneNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.08, 0.08, 0.08)
 sceneView?.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(craneNode)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your model "slides" only at the initial tracking's stage. Then it's standing still. It happens because a scene hasn't been tracked yet. If it's not true (what I'm talking about) – the problem is in `hitResult`. I did't see how you got it.

And node's order and hierarchy matters...

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "Volvo_FE_Crane_2013.dae")!

craneNode = SCNNode()
let truckNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Volvo_FE_Crane_2013", 
                                         recursively: true)!

truckNode.position = SCNVector3Make(hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x, 
                                    hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, 
                                    hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)

// truckNode.light?.intensity = 1000                  // IT"S NOT A LIGHT

truckNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.08, 0.08, 0.08)

craneNode.addChildNode(truckNode.clone())
sceneView?.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(craneNode)
```

**Also, it might be an issue with model size (number of polygons)**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had tried to use other 3d models and with that same code is working fine. I am facing issue only with a new added 3d object

Comment: What's your phone's model? And how many polygons does your model have?